# How to order rows based on different column value in an array but working individually within the matrices in R

Tags: r, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
> a
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    5    7    5
[2,]    5    3    6    7
[3,]    6    9    8    4

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    4    9    3    3
[2,]    6    4    6    5
[3,]    8    3    2    6
```

And I would like to order the rows based on decreasing values from the [,3] column. The output should be like this:

```
> Output
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    9    8    4
[2,]    3    5    7    5
[3,]    5    3    6    7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    4    6    5
[2,]    4    9    3    3
[3,]    8    3    2    6
```

I can use the `order()` function with a matrix writing something like this: `m[order(m[,3],decreasing=T),]` and I know that I should use an `apply()` function, but I'm trying to combine both and it doesn't work in my hands. I use to have those kind of problems working with arrays so any tips about where I can find good information for managing arrays are welcome. I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you make your example easy-to-paste? You can use `dput` to output object into such a format.

Comment: This is the original array: `a<-array(c(3,5,6,5,3,9,7,6,8,5,7,4,4,6,8,9,4,3,3,6,2),c(3,4,2))`. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your original question with pertinent data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a good old `for` loop to do this.

```
xy <- array(c(3,5,6,5,3,9,7,6,8,5,7,4,4,6,8,9,4,3,3,6,2),c(3,4,2))

for (i in seq_len(dim(xy)[3])) {
  myorder <- order(xy[,, i][, 3], decreasing = TRUE)
  xy[,, i] <- xy[myorder, , i]
}

> xy
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    9    8    4
[2,]    3    5    7    5
[3,]    5    3    6    7

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    6    4    6    5
[2,]    4    9    3    3
[3,]    8    3    2    6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` to combine the 3D array to 2 dimensions, then order on column 3 and use `slice.index`  to bring the positions back to correct order.

```
a[] <- apply(a, 2, c)[order(-a[,3,]),][slice.index(a, c(1,3,2))]
a
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    6    9    8    4
#[2,]    3    5    7    5
#[3,]    5    3    6    7
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    6    4    6    5
#[2,]    4    9    3    3
#[3,]    8    3    2    6
```

Data:

```
a<-array(c(3,5,6,5,3,9,7,6,8,5,7,4,4,6,8,9,4,3,3,6,2),c(3,4,2))
```